# Remove date requirement on Versions

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The current "Version" section inside Documentation require the exact date of change. This will make it difficult on topics that does not have the exact date listed on their release notes (e.g [Android Studio Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html))

I would like to request changing the date into an optional component instead of a requirement for versioning. Instead of `YYYY-mm-dd`, allow us to write `YYYY-mm`, with an optional `dd` (if any).